# Keras custom loss with missing values in multi-class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, missing-data, multiclass-classification

Hello I have training data with a lot of missing values in labels, where for example a single label can have the following values:

```
[nan, 0, 0, nan, 1, 0]
```

I would like to train a classification model that ignores the nan values. Currently I have filled the nan values with -1, and try to slice it. A mask does not work, because the categorical crossentropy still takes it into account

```
ix = tf.where(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
true = tf.gather(y_true, ix)
pred = tf.gather(y_pred, ix)
return keras.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(true, pred)
```

is what I've been able to come up with so far, but it errors with

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [131] vs. [128]
         [[Node: mul_1 = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Mean, _recv_dense_3_sample_weights_0/_13)]]
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to handle this?

Comment: Do you have this `nans` only in `y`s or also in`x`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Only in y, X is a completely filled matrix.

Comment: So how about simply skipping `x`s with missing values? For `prediction` training they are useless. You may use them only for `pretrain`.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Because it is a multi-label classification. Every x has 1064 classes, but in the training set it is so sparse that a sample only has labels for ~100 out of 1064 classes at one time.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom loss function and temporarily replace missing values with zeroes. Then after calculating cross entropy loss replace loss values in places in which the label was missing with zeroes.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()


def missing_values_cross_entropy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # We're adding a small epsilon value to prevent computing logarithm of 0 (consider y_hat == 0.0 or y_hat == 1.0).
    epsilon = tf.constant(1.0e-30, dtype=np.float32)

    # Check that there are no NaN values in predictions (neural network shouldn't output NaNs).
    y_pred = tf.debugging.assert_all_finite(y_pred, 'y_pred contains NaN')

    # Temporarily replace missing values with zeroes, storing the missing values mask for later.
    y_true_not_nan_mask = tf.logical_not(tf.math.is_nan(y_true))
    y_true_nan_replaced = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(y_true), tf.zeros_like(y_true), y_true)

    # Cross entropy, but split into multiple lines for readability:
    # y * log(y_hat)
    positive_predictions_cross_entropy = y_true_nan_replaced * tf.math.log(y_pred + epsilon)
    # (1 - y) * log(1 - y_hat)
    negative_predictions_cross_entropy = (1.0 - y_true_nan_replaced) * tf.math.log(1.0 - y_pred + epsilon)
    # c(y, y_hat) = -(y * log(y_hat) + (1 - y) * log(1 - y_hat))
    cross_entropy_loss = -(positive_predictions_cross_entropy + negative_predictions_cross_entropy)

    # Use the missing values mask for replacing loss values in places in which the label was missing with zeroes.
    # (y_true_not_nan_mask is a boolean which when casted to float will take values of 0.0 or 1.0)
    cross_entropy_loss_discarded_nan_labels = cross_entropy_loss * tf.cast(y_true_not_nan_mask, tf.float32)

    mean_loss_per_row = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy_loss_discarded_nan_labels, axis=1)
    mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(mean_loss_per_row)

    return mean_loss


y_true = tf.constant([
    [0, 1, np.nan, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, np.nan],
])

y_pred = tf.constant([
    [0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3],
    [0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0],
    [0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2],
    [0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2],
])

loss = weighted_cross_entropy_loss(y_true, y_pred)

# Extract value from EagerTensor.
print(loss.numpy())
```

outputs:

```
0.4945919
```

Use the loss function when compiling the keras model as specified in [documentation](https://keras.io/losses/):

```
model.compile(loss=missing_values_cross_entropy_loss, optimizer='sgd')
```